# Does anyone know what "mscorlib: Index was out of range" means in my vbscript code?

Tags: arraylist, vbscript, mscorlib

Here is my code:

```
dim myArrayList

function addName

    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "What is your Quarterback's name?"
    n = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine

    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Attempts: "
    a = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine

    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Completions: "
    c = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine

    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Yards: "
    y = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine

    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Touchdowns: "
    t = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine

    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Interceptions: "
    i = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine


Set myArrayList = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList" )
    myArrayList.Add n
    myArrayList.Add a
    myArrayList.Add c
    myArrayList.Add y 
    myArrayList.Add t
    myArrayList.Add i

end function 

addname()

function show
    for i = 1 to myArrayList.count
        Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine myArrayList(i)
    next
end function

show()
```

I receive an error that reads, 
"mscorlib: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and must be less of the size of the collection. Parameter name: Index"

I don't know what the problem is
Could anyone help me figure this out? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET [System.Collections.ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) class uses 0-based indexes: The first element is at index 0, and the last element is at index `Count - 1`. The last iteration of your `For` loop causes the error because it attempts to access the element at index `Count`, which doesn't exist.

Modify your `For` loop so that it counts from 0 to `myArrayList.Count - 1` instead:

```
For i = 0 To myArrayList.Count - 1
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine myArrayList(i)
Next
```